# GUI Based Workflow Tracking Solutions for Designers

Tags: software-recommendation, workflow, interface-design, freelance

I have been interested in finding a way to track my progress and tasks for client work with a visually engaging workflow program, that isn't like a git-hub style solution.

I'm looking for a program that is visually interactive, with simple tools for managing it rather than a terminal based, command line software.

Upon a search I did see a similar question **[here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/423/web-based-workflow-solutions-for-graphic-designers-hosted-and-self-run)** but it was quite old and the answers appear to be geared towards a git-hub mentality.

**What graphic user interface based software exists that would help me track my workflow effectively?**

I'm looking for both online web apps and offline local software solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Pen and Paper

When freelancing and before many options came out program wise I would always implement the pen and paper concept.  The process I chose was to create a graph style list that focused on the task, importance, priority level, difficulty, estimated time to complete task and date completed.  When I complete a paper checklist I try to measure my success rate and complete all the fairly easy tasks first.  This is important because when you visually 
see the tasks you have completed you feel a sense of joy knowing that your project is almost complete and it helps when working on the longer time consuming tasks.

### Dry Erase Board

Before computers, apps, and mobile devices in the shop I worked at we purchased two 4' x 8' dry erase boards and monitored each task and attempted to keep it up to date as best as possible but actually trying and executing this process was timely and messy.  Eventually we had to implement a certain workflow procedure on who could update and what they were 
allowed to update.

### Excel

When freelancing on my own I moved my pen and paper idea to an excel spreadsheet and created a macro to measure the time frame to track my process and what areas I needed improvement.  This is an out-dated option but still an effective one.  If I was subcontracting out some code to a friend I would use Google drive to share the spreadsheet.

### Trello

[site](http://trello.com/)

By far my favorite workflow to do list tracking.  It does have a free and paid option. The free option is great for individuals maintain their lists or in this case they are known as boards and each task or list item is known as a board.  You are allowed to migrate files from Google, Dropbox, and your computer.  I love the simplicity of this compared to all app options and how I can use it on my iPad, iPhone, Android and desktop but there are some areas of improvement it could use.

### Teambox

[site](http://teambox.com/)

Excellent option for programmers and large companies. It offers video chat and a ton of more features than Trello.  However, all the features and options for a single user are overwhelming and from a designer mentality I find it difficult to work within.  If I were ever a large 20 team crew I would certainly go this route.  There are some free options and the paid membership appears to be cheaper than Trello.  I haven't checked to see if this is offered for iPad, iPhone or android.

### Wunderlist

[site](http://www.6wunderkinder.com/wunderlist)

I haven't used or tested this option but the site seems pretty cool and I wanted to offer another suggestion so to not appear biased.  There is a paid version and free version available. It also shows that its offered for iPhone, iPad, Android, Mac, and Windows.

I also did a search for [alternatives to Trello](http://alternativeto.net/software/trello/) if any wants to explore outside the listed above.

### Evernote

[site](https://evernote.com/)

This is an old list but I thought I would update the list.  I used to be a big fan of Trello but recently I migrated to Evernote.  For the free edition it enables you to create what are called Notebooks.  Within those notebooks you can send certain members access to those notebooks and you create notes within the notebooks.  The notebooks do allow attachments, tags, announcements, and it works very well with mobile devices.  One big feature I like that is recently new is you can have chats surrounding the notebook or notes.  If you have a deadline you can even add an email reminder.